# What does file object holds itself?

Tags: python, file, concept

See the below code:

```
import os

file = open("C:/Users/AAYUSH/Desktop/file.txt", 'r' )

print(file)

for i in file:
    print(i,end="")
```

If I execute this code I got below output:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/AAYUSH/Desktop/file.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
This is first line!!!
This is second line!!!
```

My question is: If I execute `print(file)` then I got a dictionary of the file and when I write with the help of `for loop` I got inside data.

Then what actually the file object holds?

Comment: Please search for "I/O objects" in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=data%20model#data-model) and read also [here](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object). File objects or *streams* wrap other low-level objects making them present a convenient API.

Comment: These low level objects are define in `io`module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print(file)
```

Invoked tke `__str__` method of the `file` object & that happens to return a string that tells you about the type of the object i.e. `TextIOWrapper` & some attributes `name`, `r` etc. The file contents are not here because the file has not been read yet.

```
for i in file
```

Invoked the `__iter__` method of the file object & actually **does** read the file (one line at a time). The `file` object holds a pointer to a position in the file - this is used to read from it.